# How to get the output from a function

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JS. I'm trying to get the output from a function below with `return` but somehow it didn't work and only `console.log()` works.

```js
var merge = function(nums1, m, nums2, n) {
  let hasil = [];
  for (let i = 0; i <= m; i++) {
    const element = nums1[i];
    hasil.push(element);
  }
  for (let j = 0; j <= n; j++) {
    const element2 = nums2[j];
    hasil.push(element2);
  }
  let jawaban = hasil.sort();
  console.log(jawaban)
  return jawaban
};
merge([1, 2, 3], 1, [5, 9, 2], 2);
```

Comment: Welcome! Where are you trying to return this? What is the expected result?

Comment: The result of the function call must be assigned to a variable for you to get it "out" of the function, e.g. `let foo = merge([1, 2, 3], 1, [5, 9, 2], 2); console.log(foo);`.

Comment: to the merge variable,same output like console.log(jawaban) i try using return and remove the console but the answer wont come up

Comment: `var something = merge([1, 2, 3], 1, [5, 9, 2], 2);` ... now `something` will contain the result?

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding what "return" means. "return" is not "output". You "output" using `console.log` (or some other ways); but not `return`. A "return value" is the value that will be used in place where the function call is in an expression. The expression `1+2` evaluates to `3`; the expression `1+Math.sqrt(4)` is the same: the return value of `Math.sqrt(4)` is the square root of 4, which is 2; so it is evaluated just like `1+2`. Note that `2` is not "output" anywhere.

Comment: If you just write `2;` in your code, it does nothing: JS goes "huh, there's a 2 here..." and then moves on. Same if you just do `Math.sqrt(4);`. Same if you just do `merge([1, 2, 3], 1, [5, 9, 2], 2);`. "Huh, there's a `[1, 2, 2, 5, 9]`, neat." and then promptly forgets about it because you haven't told it to do anything with it (like, e.g., output it, with `console.log(merge([1, 2, 3], 1, [5, 9, 2], 2));`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try to call `merge()` function and assign the return value to a new variable. Then print it.

```js
var merge = function(nums1, m, nums2, n) {
  let hasil = [];
  for (let i = 0; i <= m; i++) {
    const element = nums1[i];
    hasil.push(element);
  }
  for (let j = 0; j <= n; j++) {
    const element2 = nums2[j];
    hasil.push(element2);
  }
  let jawaban = hasil.sort();
  return jawaban
};
let result = merge([1, 2, 3], 1, [5, 9, 2], 2);
console.log(result);
```